# How to show a ProgressDialog while changing from a activity to another activity?

Tags: android, progressdialog

i want to show a PD when my activity A starts another activity B. But in that onclick method, my A activity haves to do some work before start B, and B also haves to do some work because it haves to load a lot of data for the UI.

I need a PD that is viewed by the user in all the process of the loading data of changin from activity A to B.

¿how can do it?

i tryed storing a static ProgressDialog on MyApplication.java, and with these methods:

```
public static void showProgressDialog(Context c) {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(c, c.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), 
        c.getResources().getString(R.string.loading), true, false);    
}
public static void dismissProgressDialog(){
    pd.dismiss();
}
```

but it doesn't works, it doesn't shows nothing, i dont know why

how to achieve this by a easy way? **i know that i can do it with async task, but that is too hard for me**, i can't understand the code examples i am finding on this web and google

code examples are welcome

thanks

Comment: `i know that i can do it with async task, but that is too hard for me` I'm sorry but that's the way to do it.

Comment: can you give me easy code example that does it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, i agree with @Falmarri comment, the easy way is implementing that with an AsyncTask. Because AsyncTask manages the UIThread and a background thread.

i always do this with AsyncTask but i don´t think that paste here my code will help you, because your requirements maybe are not like mine, but i think you can do in this way;

Subclass the AsyncTask and override these methods;

- onPreExecute()...  because this
  method is invoked in the ui thread
  you can create and show the progress
  dialog.
- doInBackground(Runnable    task)...
  this method run in a    background
  thread so you don´t have    to worry
  about Threads handling...    all you
  have to do is the hard work
  (process data, download data, etc)
  and publish any update to the ui that
  you want.
- onProgressUpdate(Object... values)...
  this method also is called in the ui 
  thread, so you can update your
  progress dialog with the progress
  values.
- onPostExecute(Object    result)...
  this method run in the ui    thread
  so, you can show the operation
  result and dismiss the progress
  dialog, and invoke your new activity.

you can do all operations here, the activity A operation and activity B operation, and the AsynTask will manage for you the Threading management :)

**Edit 1:**

i don't know how much complex is your desing but here i make a project example, maybe it's not what you want but it has all stuff decribed here, in my answer, maybe like an example works.

i suggest that you read more about this class because is one of the most important, here you can read more about this mechanism... 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Comment: i dont understand it. How can know this class when is finished the code that it is executing on my activiy A and my activity B ? i can't see how can this class know it. If it doesn't know when is over the task's that A and B have to finish, then the progressdialog will be showed forever

Comment: you tell me that i can do all the operations here, but it is not possible, are a lot of operations, my app is designed in the way that these operations habe to be doned on A and B. i can't move here. A and B have thousands of lines of code. Will be take weeks or moths to move here and for sure i will face a lot of errors and problems hard to solve if i have to move the operations here

Comment: it is not possible to do a progressdialog without putting the operations on this class :S ???

Answer (score 1):

You can add a prograss bar to your layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        //your layout
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >
    </ProgressBar>

</FrameLayout>
```

Load the progress bar in your activity onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //rest your code       
}
```

Stop the progress bar when your activity starts:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {

    //your code
    mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);        
    super.onStart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a singleton instance for all the way loading/progress-dialog.
2. Use ApplicationContext for ProgressViews/dialogs
3. Manage From static functions accesible troughout app

These can be 3 ways to do so.